# How to read nested for-loops?

Tags: c, for-loop

I cannot understand what this `for-loop` does by reading the code. I know how a for-loop works though. By reading this code I literally gain no insight into what the program could be doing.

I'm coming from python to C, if that matters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int numbers[10] = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
            numbers[j] += numbers[i];

    return 0;

}
```

`for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)`

This just means iterate through each element of the array. It is easy to understand.

```
for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
                numbers[j] += numbers[i];
```

This is much harder! I think it is because I cannot figure out in my head what `j` would be equal to. I cannot follow the two loops properly.

I would specifically like to know how I can read and understand this nested for-loop in C.

(I know what this snippet does because I compiled and ran the code.)

Comment: "For each element of the array, add to it all the previous elements of the array."

Comment: Couple of ways to understand what's going on: (1) Work through the code manually using a smaller array -- say an array of 3 elements. (2) Put a print statement in the inner `for` loop to print how `numbers[j]` is changing with each iteration.

Comment: Well, for each iteration of 'j' you are adding every 'ith' element to it up to the jth value. That is what it is doing.

Comment: As another way you may examine its execution step-by-step with `gdb` debugger, printing every variable you need. It is invaluable technique to get familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's translate it into Python:

```
numbers = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(j):
        numbers[j] += numbers[i]
```

The outer loop iterates through all ten elements of `numbers` and, for each item, adds all *previous* elements in `numbers` to the *current* one. [It's easier to follow if you add a few `print` statements](http://codepad.org/fQt1v3kZ).

Answer (score 1):

`for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)` doesn't mean "iterate through each element of the array".  It means "for each value of j from 0 to 9, execute the code within the loop".

The code within the loop includes another loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
            numbers[j] += numbers[i];
```

So, for each value of j from 0 to 9, that inner loop will be executed.  In effect, it would be like executing the inner loop sequentially 10 times:

```
for (i = 0; i < 0; ++i)
            numbers[0] += numbers[i];
for (i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
            numbers[1] += numbers[i];
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            numbers[2] += numbers[i];
```

... and so on

(As a side note, the first execution of the inner loop does nothing, since 0 is not less than 0.  So the initial value of the outer loop might as well be 1.)

To return to your original phrasing, if the outer loop essentially iterates over all elements of the array, the inner loop does a second iteration over all elements of the array prior to the current element in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is helpful to just write out what is happening along the way.  Also, adding braces might help a little bit as well:

```
for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
{
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
    {
        numbers[j] += numbers[i];
    }
 }
```

(A) The first time through the outer loop, `j` will be zero, thus the inner loop will read:

```
for (i=0; i < 0; ++i)
```

because 0 is not less than 0, we skip the body of the inner loop (and numbers remains unchanged).

(B) The second time through the outer loop, `j` will be one, thus the inner loop will read:

```
for (i=0; i < 1; ++i)
```

So we will go through the body of the inner-loop once with `i` being zero, thus we will execute this 
command; `numbers[1] = numbers[1] + numbers[0];` (I expanded += for added clarity) which will now make the numbers array look like this: 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

(C) The third time through the outer loop, `j` will be two, thus the inner loop will read:

```
for(i=0; i < 2; ++i)
```

SO we will go through the body of the inner-loop twice with `i` being first zero, and then one.  Thus 
we will execute the following commands:

```
numbers[2] = numbers[2] + numbers[0];
numbers[2] = numbers[2] + numbers[1];
```

which will transform the numbers array into 1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

and so on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `j`th element in the `numbers` array is the sum of all preceding elements in the array. Technically, the preceding elements gets *added to* the `j`th element, but `numbers[j]` is 0 to begin with.

When `j` equals 1,

```
numbers[1] = numbers[1] + numbers[0]
```

which makes `numbers[1]` == 1. (because `i` can only be 0 and `numbers[0]` is 1)

When `j` equals 2,

```
numbers[2] = numbers[2] + numbers[1] + numbers[0]
```

which makes `numbers[2]` == 2. (because `i` can be 0 and 1, and `numbers[0]` and `numbers[1]` are both 1)

When `j` equals 3,

```
numbers[3] = numbers[3] + numbers[2] + numbers[1] + numbers[0]
```

which makes `numbers[3]` == 4. (because `i` can be 0, 1 and 2, and `numbers[2]` is 2)

As such, any `j - 1`th (`j` > 1) element equals the sum of all of its preceding elements. Hence, as the loop goes on, the `j`th element would end up becoming the double of the `j - 1`th element.

At the end of the program, each value in the array would be `1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256`

Answer (score 0):

here is the value of your array after each outer loop

```
  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   1   2   4   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   1   2   4   8   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   1   2   4   8  16   0   0   0   0 
  1   1   2   4   8  16  32   0   0   0 
  1   1   2   4   8  16  32  64   0   0 
  1   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128   0 
  1   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128 256
```

as generated by this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

void show_numbers(int size_array, int index, int given_array[]) {

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < size_array; i++) {

        printf("%3d ", given_array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main (void) {

    // static const int size_array = 10;
    int numbers[SIZE_ARRAY] = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i, j;

    show_numbers(SIZE_ARRAY, 0, numbers);

    for (j = 0; j < SIZE_ARRAY; ++j) {

        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {

            numbers[j] += numbers[i];
        }

        show_numbers(SIZE_ARRAY, j, numbers);
    }
    return 0;

}
```